# How to use a custom JSON Serializer in Servicestack?

Tags: json, serialization, servicestack

I am wondering how you can use a custom JSON Serializer in ServiceStack. I am aware of the JsConfig.SerializeFn/DeSerializeFn but these seem to always 'JSON.stringify' the result of my custom Serializer.

I like to replace Serialization for the whole DTO. The endresult should be something like

```
{"Name":"Greg"}
```

and not

```
"{\"Name\":\"Greg\"}"
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 7):

In terms of other hooks in [ServiceStack's JSON Serializers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/) there's also `JsConfig<T>.RawSerializeFn` and `JsConfig<T>.RawDeserializeFn` which should do what you need.

Otherwise if you just want to some pre/post processing there's also the `JsConfig<T>.OnSerializingFn` and `JsConfig<T>.OnDeserializedFn` custom hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use `ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(object, typeof(object))`?  If you using it in a view in .net you might need to use `Html.Raw(ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(object, typeof(object)))`.