# Including/Excluding null values at a DTO level - Service Stack

Tags: servicestack

Is it possible in service stack to include/exclude null values at a DTO/property level rather than on the whole using "JsConfig.IncludeNullValues". I have a scenario where i need specific responses to have null values in the returned JSON.

Comment: Please refer the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881270/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-default-values-during-serialization-with-servicestack-j

Answer (score 2):

Using JsConfig scope block, just drop these lines into your `AppHost` `Configure` method:

```
JsConfig<NotNullDtoResponse>.RawSerializeFn = (obj) =>
{
    using(JsConfig.With(new Config { IncludeNullValues = true }))
    {
        return obj.ToJson();
    }
};

JsConfig<NotNullDtoResponse>.RawDeserializeFn = (json) =>
{
    using(JsConfig.With(new Config { IncludeNullValues = true }))
    {
        return JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<NotNullDtoResponse>(json);
    }
};
```

NotNullDtoResponse is your responseDTO